# Boost Timer 24 hour format

Tags: c++, boost, timer, formatting, duration

I'm using `boost::timer::cpu_timer` to calculate the "user process time" of an algorithm like so:

```
boost::timer::cpu_timer timer;

boost::timer::nanosecond_type userTime = timer.elapsed().user;
```

My question is how do I format `userTime` in `HH::MM::SS.mmm` format? I know I can write the code myself, but I was expecting Boost to provide some means of doing this.

I came across [this example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/chrono/users_guide.html#chrono.users_guide.examples.time_point.24_hours_display), but it makes use of `boost::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>`, which I'm not sure how to obtain from `boost::timer::nanosecond_type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need conversion `nanosecond_type` to `duration` to `time_point`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>

namespace chrono = boost::chrono;

int main()
{
    // get now time & start timer
    chrono::system_clock::time_point start_time = chrono::system_clock::now();
    boost::timer::cpu_timer timer;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {}

    // elapsed time conversion to time_point
    chrono::system_clock::time_point end_time
        = chrono::time_point_cast<chrono::system_clock::duration>(
                start_time + chrono::nanoseconds(timer.elapsed().user));

    // time_point conversion to time_t&tm
    std::time_t time = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(end_time);
    std::tm* t = std::localtime(&time);

    // formatting
    std::size_t fractional_seconds = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(
                                        end_time.time_since_epoch()
                                     ).count() % 1000;
    std::string s = (boost::format("%d:%d:%d.%d")
                        % t->tm_hour
                        % t->tm_min
                        % t->tm_sec
                        % fractional_seconds
                    ).str();
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

possible output:

```
10:42:55.445
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but perhaps somebody else has a cleaner solution. It seems overkill to do so many conversions just to format time (even though this allows flexible formatting). I find it really strange that there is no duration formatting in `boost::chrono`...

Comment: Now version boost::chrono is time utility (not date time library). So, chrono/date is now developing. https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/chrono_date/libs/date/doc/date.html I believe future version is more useful.